# Passing a spread object as a prop on a conditional basis

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which is currently taking in a object value as a prop which is being spread.

```
const primaryProps = {/* about 10 key/values in here */}

<Component
  {...primaryProps}
/>
```

This works as intended. But now I am try to add an `OR` to it and add another object which is spread. But this is throwing syntax errors. Is there a way around it? Thanks.

Tried following which doesn't work.

```
const primaryProps = {/* about 10 key/values in here. Can also be empty/null */}
const secondaryProps = {/* about 10 key/values in here */}

<Component
  {...primaryProps || ...secondaryProps}
/>


<Component
  `${primaryProps.join(",") || secondaryProps.join(",")}`
/>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Spread either the primary or the secondary object, but based on what condition? Or do you want to spread both?

Comment: @Reyno If primaryProps has data, spread that and pass that as a prop. Else spread secondaryProps and pass that as a prop.

Comment: @stacky What exactly do you mean by "has data"? Is there a case where it's not an object but `null` or `undefined`? Or do you want to do this defaulting logic on each individual property?

Comment: So you want to merge `secondaryProps` into `primaryProps` if `condition === true` ?

Comment: @Bergi As mentioned above, primaryProps can be null or undefined. In that instance, go for secondaryProps, spread that and send as a prop. Not individual property. Just the overall object. If primary is null, use secondary.

Comment: @0stone0 Not merging. If primary is null, use secondary.

Comment: Please add the error. `{ ...primary || secondary }` works just fine!

Comment: @stacky in that case, go for Baker's answer. Remeber that spread syntax is part of the object literal syntax, you cannot write "if x then spread y else spread z", just like you cannot place property names or multiple property definitions inside a conditional clause in an object literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt:

```
<Component
  {...primaryProps || ...secondaryProps}
/>
```

Won't work because you don't need to spread the `secondaryProps`.

If `primaryProps` is NULL `secondaryProps` will be used with the first spread syntax

---

So remove the second `...` and use:

```
<Component { ...primaryProps || secondaryProps } />;
```

---

Small example, toggle `primary` to see it in action

```js
class Child extends React.Component {  
    render() {
        return Object.values(this.props);
    }
}

class Example extends React.Component {    
    render() {
        // const primary = { foo: 'primary' };
        const primary = null;
        const secondary  = { bar: 'secondary' };
        
        return <Child { ...primary || secondary } />;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass `secondaryProps` only when the `primaryProps` are `null` or `undefined` you can do it like that (but note that this will not work if the passed object is defined but empty):

```
<Component {...(primaryProps ?? secondaryProps)} />
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible to do inside the props of a component. Also it isn't clean. What would I suggest is take the condition out of the component.

```
const props = condition ? primaryProps : secondaryProps
<Component {...props} />
```

Comment: It's totally possible to write `<Component {...primaryProps || secondaryProps}>`

Comment: This would work. Just trying to see if I could just do it when passing the prop itself instead of another variable.